# NumberPicker showing wrong values with custom text when `value=1`

Tags: android, setvalue, numberpicker

I'm trying to make NumberPicker show a custom set of selections and to start with the second item in the list (`value=1`). The selections are: C♭, C, C#, D♭, and D, and the picker *should* show "C" for the second item, but instead it's showing "C♭" with two "C♭" items in the list:

[image: Screenshot of NumberPicker misbehaving and showing two "C♭" instead of one "C" and one "C♭".]

Using touch input to scroll the NumberPicker "fixes" this, but that's not really a fix because users won't want to have to interact with the view to make it show the correct value. It should display correctly from the start. And it only seems to happen when the "C♭" comes first, "C" comes second, and I set the value to `1` (so, the "C"). The bug doesn't happen if I set the value to 0 or 2, or if the "C#" comes first, or if the C comes first.

Here's my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/npExample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my Kotlin:

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    var npExample : NumberPicker? = null

    val exampleValues = arrayOf(
        "C♭",
        "C",
        "C#",
        "D♭",
        "D"
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        npExample = findViewById(R.id.npExample)
        npExample!!.minValue = 0
        npExample!!.maxValue = exampleValues.size - 1
        npExample!!.displayedValues = exampleValues
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Read the value we need from preferences here.
        // For this example, we just hard-code the value into Kotlin to demo the behavior.
        val exampleValue = 1
        npExample?.value = exampleValue
    }

}
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I checked your implementation as well as another list of elements. It turned out that this is a problem of rendering a specific element. For example, if you take a list with elements like "value 1" and so on, then everything will work correctly.


I haven't figured out yet why this problem is happening in your case, but I would recommend trying to used a custom library for NumberPicker and test with it.